# JBehave Stories will not run as Embeddables

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, jbehave

I have been attempting to run concurrent, multi-threaded stories using JBehave. They run correctly when using the embedder, but when running them as embeddables, they don't execute. When I change the source directories or the scope, I get a nullpointerException and when I comment them out, it builds successfully but does not find the class "My-ProgramStories.java." When I execute them using Maven with "mvn clean verify" this is what is returning (sorry for the ugly formatting):

> [INFO] --- jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.5:run-stories-as-embeddables (embeddable-stories) @  program-test> ---
>   [INFO] Running stories as embeddables using embedder
>   Embedder[storyMapper=StoryMapper,storyRunner=StoryRunner,
>   embedderMonitor=MavenEmbedderMonitor,classLoader=EmbedderClassLoader[urls=[/Users//Documents/Repositories///target/test-classes/,
>   /Users//Documents/Repositories///target/classes,
>   groovy-all-1.8.4.jar],parent=ClassRealm[plugin>org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.5,
>   parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1729854]],embedderControls=
>   UnmodifiableEmbedderControls[EmbedderControls[batch=false,skip=false,generateViewAfterStories
>   true,ignoreFailureInStories=true,ignoreFailureInView=true,verboseFailures=false,
>   verboseFiltering=false,storyTimeoutInSecs=400,threads=4]],
>   embedderFailureStrategy=org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$ThrowingRunningStoriesFailed@127c1
>   ee,configuration=org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration@10c56cbd,candidateSte
>   s=[],stepsFactory=,metaFilters=[groovy: story_path ==~ /.*.story/],systemProperties
>   {},executorService=,executorServiceCreated=false,storyManager=]
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 1:04.710s
>   [INFO] Finished at: Mon Jul 29 09:55:43 CDT 2013
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 60M/123M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.5:run-stories-as
>   embeddables (embeddable-stories) on project : Failed to run stories as
>   embeddables: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]

This is how I have the JBehave Maven Plugin configured in the POM:

```
<properties>
   <embeddables>**/My-ProgramStories.java</embeddables>
   <ignore.failre.in.stories>true</ignore.failre.in.stories>
   <meta.filter>groovy: story_path ==~ /.*.story/</meta.filter>
   <threads>4</threads>
   <story.timeout.in.secs>400</story.timeout.in.secs>
</properties>
```

...

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <id>embeddable-stories</id>
                  <phase>integration-test</phase>
                     <configuration>
                        <includes>
                           <include>${embeddables}</include>
                        </includes>
                        <excludes>
                           <exclude>${exclude}</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/test/java</sourceDirectory>
                        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/resources</testSourceDirectory>
                        <skip>${skip}</skip>
                        <batch>false</batch>
                        <threads>${threads}</threads>
                        <storyTimeoutInSecs>${story.timeout.in.secs}</storyTimeoutInSecs>
                        <generateViewAfterStories>true</generateViewAfterStories>
                        <ignoreFailureInStories>
                           ${ignore.failre.in.stories}
                        </ignoreFailureInStories>
                        <ignoreFailureInView>true</ignoreFailureInView>
                        <metaFilters>
                           <metaFilter>${meta.filter}</metaFilter>
                        </metaFilters>
                     </configuration>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                     </goals>
                  </execution>
               </executions>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
         <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
         <version>1.8.4</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

The structure of my story and test classes along with my story files as viewed through Eclipse is the following:

> my-program-test
>   -->src/test/java
>   ---->package1
>   ------>My-ProgramSteps.java
>   ------>My-ProgramStories.java
>   -->src/test/resources
>   ---->package1
>   ------>Story Files

Here is the stacktrace of the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.5:run-stories-as-embeddables (embeddable-stories) on project my-program: Failed to run stories as embeddables: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jbehave:jbehave-maven-plugin:3.7.5:run-stories-as-embeddables (embeddable-stories) on project my-program-test: Failed to run stories as embeddables
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Failed to run stories as embeddables
>       at org.jbehave.mojo.RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.execute(RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.java:20)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>       ... 19 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner.normalizePattern(AbstractScanner.java:327)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner.setExcludes(AbstractScanner.java:314)
>       at org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder.scanDirectory(StoryFinder.java:218)
>       at org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder.scan(StoryFinder.java:205)
>       at org.jbehave.core.io.StoryFinder.findClassNames(StoryFinder.java:61)
>       at org.jbehave.mojo.AbstractEmbedderMojo.classNames(AbstractEmbedderMojo.java:302)
>       at org.jbehave.mojo.RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.execute(RunStoriesAsEmbeddables.java:18)
>       ... 21 more

Comment: Can you run maven with `-e` so it prints out the stacktrace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
   org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner.normalizePattern(AbstractScanner.java:327) at
   org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner.setExcludes(AbstractScanner.java:314) at
```

Looks like your exclusion pattern configuration is broken. It would look like this:

```
<exclude>${exclude}</exclude>
```

is not defined in your properties. You could use effective-pom to confirm if all properties are properly expanded.